# Left align gt table in flexdashboard

Tags: r, flexdashboard, gt

I have flexdashboard with runtime: shiny. When I create gt table it is center align, how do I make it left align? I plan to eventually render gt table.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
   vertical_layout: fill 
   theme: 
      version: 4
      bootswatch: minty
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Row {data-height=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
library(gt)

gt(head(iris)) %>%
  tab_options(data_row.padding = px(1))
```

### Chart A
```{r}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to set `table.align="left"` in `tab_options()`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
   vertical_layout: fill 
   theme: 
  version: 4
  bootswatch: minty
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Row {data-height=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

<br>

```{r}
library(gt)

gt(head(iris)) %>%
  tab_options(
    data_row.padding = px(1),
    table.align = "left"
  )
```

### Chart B
```{r}
```
````

[image]